# How to pay a traffic fine received in Norway?

Tags: driving, norway

I received a fine in Norway for exceeding the speed limit by 9 km (60 km / h). The fine is 225 euros. I wanted to pay on the spot but they did not accept.

They told me to pay it within 14 days. I'll be back in the country after 30 days. What to do? I did not get the picture of mw speeding: the police say they do not have the picture.

Is it fair not to show me the picture of me speeding? Is the fine valid without a speeding photo?

What happens if I pay late? What if I do not pay?

Thank you.

Comment: Even if the other question is about a Norwegian customs fine, the answer is the same. I suppose that you were caught by the police in a mobile speed trap and not by a stationary radar/camera combo? I don't know why you think a picture is necessary to fine you. A stationary picture could in no way prove or disprove that you were actually speeding.

Comment: No, my question is different.

Comment: That's right, it was a mobile radar placed by the police.

Comment: You have to explain why your question is different, not just state it. To me, there is no relevant difference between your question and the question I am linking to.

Comment: my question is if I can pay after 30 days or I have to wait for the fine to be paid by post.

Comment: I already explained in my answer to the other question how to pay Norwegian fines from abroad. There is no reason why you should wait until you come back to Norway to pay the fine.

Comment: The phrase "circulation fine" seems to apply to libraries rather than automobiles, so I changed it.  But I don't know what you mean by "overcoming."   What do you mean by it?

Comment: ok.I wanted to write: overtaking legal speed

Comment: There are a number of languages where the word for 'traffic' sounds like 'circulation', so the English word 'circulation' becomes a [false friend](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_friend) for traffic.

Answer (score 3):

I've never been fined in Norway, but procedures are pretty similar in most countries.

First, a photo is not usually needed to make a speeding fine valid. If you think you were not speeding you can contest the fine in court and the police will produce whatever evidence they have that you were speeding. A photo may or may not be included.

When you were given the ticket you should also have been given instructions on how to pay it. Most jurisdictions allow you to pay in person, or online, or by mail, and possibly over the phone by credit card. It's extremely likely that your fine is payable through the Norwegian Government Collections Agency. Details of how to pay through this agency are given in the answer to [this question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/108706/how-to-pay-a-norwegian-customs-penalty-fine-from-abroad).

In most cases it works that you are fined a certain amount, but that if you pay within a certain time (14 days in your case) they will accept a lower amount. So if you pay after 14 days the fine will be more. However in my experience if you send in the payment by mail before 14 days is up and it arrives a day or two after the 14 days is up they will accept it anyway. Usually but not always.

If you do not pay then the fine remains on your record and you may have trouble if you go back to Norway. What kind of trouble is also covered by the above question.